# Freesound API, POST Request Example Returns Error

Tags: html, json, rest, post

I've been attempting to program something that interacts with Freesound.org's API, in a way similar to this example given in the Freesound API documentation...

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Token {{your_api_key}}" -F 
analysis_file=@"/path/to/your_file.json" 
'https://www.freesound.org/apiv2/search/content/'
```

... But when I run this with my details replaced, I get this error:

{"detail":"The similarity server could not be reached or some unexpected error occurred."}

I wonder if anybody knows what might might be the cause of this? As no other info is given and I'm not experienced with restfulness etc.

It seems likely to me that the JSON is not formatted properly? But it was generated with precisely the application the documentation refers to in the example I got that code from. This is that JSON:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjpf9zzftsxzoar/test.json?dl=0

I'd be very grateful for any help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your json in online validator like jsonlint.com. And it shows the  json content is a valid one.

Do you happen to know what is the error code its returning.

Comment: OK, it's valid JSON. I'm trying it out in PAW to see if there's any info I'm missing. These images show request and response: https://imgur.com/a/p41O0

Comment: Your https://i.imgur.com/WNRUuMj.png shows its 500. It could be two reasons. 1. The server is not reachable or 2. The json body is not being recognized by the server and it could not able to process it.

Comment: Also what happens when you do a GET and compare the content with your post body to see if you get any hint.

Comment: All seems fine with a GET. I've gotten the request in PAW to look just like their example, and the response says {"detail":"JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"}, but I've checked it's a valid JSON :/ here are images: https://imgur.com/a/BplzL

Comment: Can you test if there is a difference in calling the curl using https over http. Your GET call shows http and POST shows https, just a thought.

Comment: No change between http and https. I think it's probably something to do with the JSON, because of "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded". Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm getting from the request, looking at it in PAW:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbQ98.jpg